# Yii accessRules() authorization method issues - getting 403 error

Tags: yii

Instead of using the raw username / password generated by Gii, I'm trying to implement a database to store those username/passwords as well as a role field.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `role` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `create_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
  KEY `superuser` (`role`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I'm struggling to understand this:

```
array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
    'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
    'users'=>array('admin'),
),
```

I'm getting:

> 403 unauthorised

If I use `@` it works. So, I'm clearly missing a connection here, between the user array contents, and the database `username`.

How can I properly connect the `'admin'` to the database `username` field?

Can I have a push please?

Comment: `var_dump(Yii::app()->getUser()->getName());`

Comment: @cetver: Found the issue. :) The username was pointing to the email database field, and that field was empty. Fixed. Thanks. ;)